# How to use widgets in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use a number of them, but I'm starting with `NumberPicker` which extends `LinearLayout` and thus cannot just instantiate an instance in the middle of a view. Just want an embedded numeric spinner as a way of inputting a value of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [Android Views in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose) for every widget for which a specific composable has not yet been created.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomView() {
    val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    // Adds view to Compose
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), // Occupy the max size in the Compose UI tree
        factory = { context ->
            // Creates custom view
            CustomView(context).apply {
                // Sets up listeners for View -> Compose communication
                myView.setOnClickListener {
                    selectedItem.value = 1
                }
            }
        },
        update = { view ->
            // View's been inflated or state read in this block has been updated
            // Add logic here if necessary

            // As selectedItem is read here, AndroidView will recompose
            // whenever the state changes
            // Example of Compose -> View communication
            view.coordinator.selectedItem = selectedItem.value
        }
    )
}
```